# How to use Drawer without Scaffold.drawer?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've noticed that Drawer of Scaffold.drawer only shows up when an AppBar of Scaffold is present.

But Instead of AppBar,I Used BottomAppBar present in BottomNavigationBar.

How do I get Drawer working with BottomAppBar?
Here's my code Below for which Drawer dosen't appear

```
class homieclass extends State<homie>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.9),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){},backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,child: ImageIcon(new AssetImage("ast/hello123.png")),),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: (){}),IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.message), onPressed: (){}),
        ],
        ),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[new SizedBox(height: 50.0, ),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),child: new Text("Events",textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'ssfr',fontSize: 35.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),)
            , Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0) ,width: 360.0,height: 40.0,decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.2),
              border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.0), width: 2.0),
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),child: new Row(children: <Widget>[SizedBox(width: 10.0,),Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.9),),Text(" Search",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'ssft',color: Colors.blueGrey,fontSize: 20.0),)],),)
          ,new SizedBox(height: 10.0,),new SizedBox(
            height: 5.0,
            child: new Center(
              child: new Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 1.0),
                height: 2.0
                ,
                color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.8),
              ),
            ),
          ),],
        ),drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[ListTile(title: Text("hello"),)],
        ),
      ),

      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works perfectly for me. Here is a working example with a dedicated "Show Drawer" button in the bottom bar (the drawer can also be dragged in from the left):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Playground',
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Body'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();;
              }),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.message), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
        );
        },),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: SafeArea(
          right: false,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Drawer content'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter version: Latest master build (though I'm also quite sure that it works with the beta version)

Comment: thanks for showing .. but i am receiving the following error: the method openDrawer was called on null. i created the{{ global key final scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();}} .  then wrote this in onpressed = {    scaffoldkey.currentState.openDrawer();}.     Any Ideas?

Comment: That's why I wrapped the `BottomAppBar` in a `Builder` widget so that its `context` has access to the scaffold. If you do not want to use a `Builder`, but a `GlobalKey`, you have to make sure that the `id` parameter of your `Scaffold` is set to that id: `Scaffold(id: scaffoldKey, ...)`

Comment: If the answer helped you, please upvote and accept it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer how to use Drawer without Scaffold.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Drawer, but you must supply a `DrawerController`, and also arrange for the drawer to overlay your other content. This is easy to do with a `Stack`. Its important that the stack hold a non-transparent container, otherwise you'll get rendering artifacts when the draw slides in and out. Scaffold doesn't require this, however, annoyingly, it also rebuild the other content as the draw moves (exactly the type of thing they've tried to avoid).

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterui/util/layout_util.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Playground',
          home: Material(child:DrawerStack(body: body(), drawer: _drawer())));
}

Drawer _drawer() =>Drawer(
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('endDrawer content'),
          Builder(builder:(context) => RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Click', semanticsLabel: 'Click 2'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

Widget body() => Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(children: [
      Text('Body'), // style:TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.black)),
      Builder(builder:(context) => RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open drawer'),
          onPressed: () {
            (context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(DrawerStack) as DrawerStack).openDrawer();
//            DrawerStack.of(context).openDrawer();
          })),
    ]))));


class DrawerStack extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<DrawerControllerState> _drawerKey =
  GlobalKey<DrawerControllerState>();
  final drawerScrimColor = Color.fromARGB(90, 100, 100, 128);
  final double drawerEdgeDragWidth = null;
  final DragStartBehavior drawerDragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start;

  final Widget body;
  final Drawer drawer;

  DrawerStack({Key key, this.body, this.drawer}) : super(key: key);

  void openDrawer() {
    _drawerKey.currentState?.open();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Stack(
    children: [
      // body
      body,

      DrawerController(
        key: _drawerKey,
        alignment: DrawerAlignment.end,
        child: drawer,
        drawerCallback: (_){},
        dragStartBehavior: drawerDragStartBehavior,
        //widget.drawerDragStartBehavior,
        scrimColor: drawerScrimColor,
        edgeDragWidth: drawerEdgeDragWidth,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really good. I wanted to add drawer functionality in bottom sheet. So using `Scaffold` was not an option, because it would be shown behind the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can `openDrawer` of `global key` from the flutter itself to do the job.

1. Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer() / Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
2. scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(); / scaffoldKey.currentState..openEndDrawer();

`Case 1`

```
bottomNavigationBar:BottomAppBar(
      elevation: 10,
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                    Text(
                      'DASHBOARD',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.home),
                    Text(
                      'CHALLENGES',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){},
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.public),
                    Text(
                      'Public',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.sentiment_satisfied),
                    Text(
                      'Settings',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      color: AppColors.WHITE,
    );
```

`Case 2`
or you can scaffold key

```
class BottomBar {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          elevation: 10,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: Container(
            height: 80,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                      // scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer(); // use to open end drawer
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                        Text(
                          'DASHBOARD',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.home),
                        Text(
                          'CHALLENGES',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.public),
                        Text(
                          'Public',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.sentiment_satisfied),
                        Text(
                          'Settings',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          color: AppColors.WHITE,
        ));
  }
}
```